# How to display the added value in correct format in Angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have added the below question using textarea.

```
What will be the output of the program?

     String x = new String("xyz");
     String y = "abc";
     x = x y;

 How many String objects have been created?
```

But when i try to list the added question in another page I saw as  `What will be the output of the program? String x = new String("xyz"); String y = "abc"; x = x y; How many String objects have been created?` (question in same line).

The response I am getting from backend is **`"question: "What will be the output of the program?↵↵String x = new String("xyz");↵String y = "abc";↵x = x   y;↵↵How many String objects have been created?"`**

In my response I am getting enter(↵) symbol but I need help to display the question in correct format.

Comment: Use CSS ~ `white-space: pre;` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `white-space` property. There are three values of a `white-space` property that will help you to accomplish your goal. They are:

`pre`   Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the  tag in HTML

`pre-line`  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

`pre-wrap`  Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

Example:

HTML

`<p> this 
is
my
multilane
text</p>`

CSS

`p{white-space: pre-wrap}`

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp